# how do i pass a view variable to the controller in codeigniter?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, codeigniter

My View :-

```
 <html>
<?= link_tag(base_url().'css/simple.css'); ?>
<body>
<?php $this->load->helper('form'); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('commentform'); ?>
<?php $id=$this->uri->segment(3);?>
<?php echo $id;?>
</body>
</html>
```

i would like to use the variable `$id` in my controller.I'm using codeigniter by the way, and am a beginner. I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, ideally you wouldn't do it this way. You should assign the variable first in the controller and pass it to the view if you need to use it there.

```
$data['id'] = $this->uri->segment(3);
$this->load->view('view_file', $data);
```

$id would then be available in your view as well.

Comment: actually,i would like to retrieve the uri segment of the view page,so that it can be passed on to the model via the controller. if i do it your way,i will be able to retrieve only the uri segment of the controller right? pardon me if i'm wrong.

Comment: The controller class name and function name is what defines the URL. For instance, if you're controller is called 'mycontroller' and your function is called 'myfunction' then the URL would be yourdomain.com/mycontroller/myfunction/ - segment three in this case would be a parameter on 'myfunction'... have a look at this for more info: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html

Answer (score 1):

you should not call the $id from the View, you should get it at the controller level and pass it to the View.

as Bulk said. you URL will be something like that
 www.mysite.com/thecontrollername/thefunction/id

for example your controller if home and there is a show_id function in it and your view is call show_id_view.php.

you will have your url like this: www.mysite.com/home/show_id/id

your function in home will read the id"

in your home controller:

```
function show_id(){
$id=$this->uri->segment(3);
$view_data['id'] = $id;
$this->load->view('show_id_view',$view_data);  
}
```

in the view (show_id_view):

```
<?php echo $id ?>
```

nothing else..

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

in my view i add link

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>link/show_id/mantap"> coba </li>
```

in my **link.php** controler i add function  show_id

```
function show_id(){
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['coba'] = $id;
        $this->mobile->view('**daftarmember_form**',$data);
```

in my next view **daftarmember_form.html**

)

```
<?php echo $id;?>
```

they print mantap,