# Use uri segment in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a variable from view to controller, from html to php, I tried searching in search engines how to do that in Codeigniter, and I found that I need to use uri segment. I don't know how to do this. I donMt understand where and how I can use uri.

I want pass variable $id via link

```
<div class="content-primary">   
  <ol data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-inset="true">
    <?php if(isset($record)) :
      foreach ($record as $row) :?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>link?$id"> <?php echo $row->username;?></a></li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
      <h2> No activiti </h2>
    <?php endif;?>
  </ol>
</div><!--/content-primary -->      
</div>
```

I want to pass `$id` to my controller

Comment: just read the manual http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484000/how-do-i-pass-a-view-variable-to-the-controller-in-codeigniter

Comment: done tq i understand now

Comment: The CodeIgniter documentation is idiot-proof.  Seriously, it would only take a few hours to read the entire CodeIgniter manual; including doing the live demos and tutorials.

Comment: tq ack it really solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484000/how-do-i-pass-a-view-variable-to-the-controller-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my view i add link

```
 <li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>link/show_id/mantap"> coba </li>
```

in my **link.php** controler i add function  show_id

```
function show_id(){
        $id=$this->uri->segment(3);
        $data['coba'] = $id;
        $this->mobile->view('**daftarmember_form**',$data);
```

in my next view **daftarmember_form.html**

)

```
<?php echo $id;?>
```

they print mantap,

Answer (score 2):

You want to change the 3d line of code from this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()?>link?$id"> <?php echo $row->username;?>
```

to this:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url()."YOUR_CONTROLER/YOUR_FUNCTION/".$id; ?> <?php echo $row->username; ?>
```

That will result in a link like:

> http://yourwebsite.com/YOUR_CONTROLER/YOUR_FUNCTION/ID

And in your controller, you can access and use "ID" in the "YOUR_FUNCTION" method.

Comment: if i had that they say page not found cos link.php is my controller, for exemple if id = 1, so the link will be link/1, that not go to my controller

Comment: What is "link" as you refer in "link/1" ? Normally following my example, you should be ending with: "http://base_url/controler/function/ID"

Comment: ok done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484000/how-do-i-pass-a-view-variable-to-the-controller-in-codeigniter

Comment: You're welcome, and don't forget to validate (or write) the correct answer.

Comment: i cant must be 10 reputaion first